# c# ObjectListView - Not updating sorting after a vlue is changed

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I am using ObjectListView to display a dictionary values, it's work perfect but when i sort it sort one time, i mean when i sort by age descending, it's sort them like `{30, 27, 26, 15, 10}`

here is an example of my object class

```
public class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    int age = -1;
    public Int32 Age
    {
        get{return age;} 
        set
        {
            if (value == age)
                return;
            this.age = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Age");
        }
    }
}
```

Also here is how i append the objects list to the list-view

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
try
{
    this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor;
    stopWatch.Start();
    this.listview1.SetObjects(this.ItemsDictionary.Values);
}
finally
{
    stopWatch.Stop();
    this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
}
```

i used

```
this.listview1.Update();
```

but i know this is updating painting of the control not the sorting.

If the object of age 15 is updated (increased or decreased) the sorting is not updated and it's still in the same position, What i need to do to make it auto-sort-update when any value of sort column is changed?

Comment: I think you need to call `this.listview1.Update();` each time you modify the list.

Comment: i modify a property that's updating the value in the list-view, anyway i tried this option but no changes happened

Comment: Can you post the full code where you are modifying and again updating the objectlistview?

Comment: Main post is edited, I've added example of how i am communicating with this control.

Comment: Before you do `this.listview1.SetObjects(this.ItemsDictionary.Values);` ensure that you have updated values in `ItemsDictionary` and then call `this.listview1.Update();`.

Comment: i am already after updating values i do update to the list-view, but to affect :(

Comment: When you are updating the values `ItemsDictionary`, put a debugger before calling `listview1.SetObjects` and check the items within `ItemsDictionary` and see if they are the updated ones. After that you will call `this.listview1.Update();`. I might also suggest you to clear the old items before `SetObjects`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by using this code with each item i update

```
    this.listview1.Sort(this.listview1.LastSortColumn);
    this.listview1.UpdateObject(OBJ);
```

Maybe this helps anyone else.

Comment: This was actually a conscious design decision. When a model is updated via `INotifyPropertyChanged`, the control only refreshes that model and specifically does not try to resort the control. Resorting the control is expensive compared to just rebuilding one row (which is quick). If you wanted to ask, I could add an "auto-resort" option: https://sourceforge.net/p/objectlistview/feature-requests/

Comment: I wasn't know before about a property called 'auto-resort', or it wasn't in the version i used in this question time, so i appreciate you response as it helpfull for me & others.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
listView.SetObjects(iEnumerable)
```

Comment: Same as listView.AddObjects(iEnumerable);
Tried.

Comment: Are you using any binding mechanism?

Comment: Nope.
its a collection of objects (class contains some variables) , i update the object value but its not updating the sorting as i explained in the main post